# spark-submit in deploy mode client not reading all the jars

Tags: apache-spark, jar, submit

I'm trying to submit an application to my spark cluster (standalone mode) through the spark-submit command. I'm following the
[official spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html), as well as relying on [this other one](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-submit.html). Now the problem is that I get strange behaviors. My setup is the following:

- I have a directory where all the dependency jars for my application are located, that is `/home/myuser/jars`
- The jar of my application is in the same directory (`/home/myuser/jars`), and is called `dat-test.jar`
- The entry point class in `dat-test.jar` is at the package path `my.package.path.Test`
- Spark master is at `spark://master:7077`

Now, I submit the application directly on the master node, thus using the `client` deploy mode, running the command

`./spark-submit --class my.package.path.Test --master spark://master:7077 --executor-memory 5G --total-executor-cores 10 /home/myuser/jars/*`

and I received an error as

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.path.Test`

If I activate the `verbose` mode, what I see is that the `primaryResource` selected as jar containing the entry point is the first jar by alphabetical order in `/home/myuser/jars/` (that is not `dat-test.jar`), leading (I supppose) to the `ClassNotFoundException`. All the jars in the same directory are anyway loaded as arguments.

Of course if I run

`./spark-submit --class my.package.path.Test --master spark://master:7077 --executor-memory 5G --total-executor-cores 10 /home/myuser/jars/dat-test.jar`

it finds the `Test` class, but it doesn't find other classes contained in other jars. Finally, if I use the `--jars` flag and run

`./spark-submit --class my.package.path.Test --master spark://master:7077 --executor-memory 5G --total-executor-cores 10 --jars /home/myuser/jars/* /home/myuser/jars/dat-test.jar`

I obtain the same result as the first option. First jar in `/home/myuser/jars/` is loaded as `primaryResource`, leading to `ClassNotFoundException` for `my.package.path.Test`. Same if I add `--jars /home/myuser/jars/*.jar`.

Important points are:

- I do not want to have a single jar with all the dependencies for development reasons
- The jars in `/home/myuser/jars/` are many. I'd like to know if there's a way to include them all instead of using the comma separated syntax
- If I try to run the same commands with `--deploy-cluster` on the master node, I don't get the error, but the computation fails for some other reasons (but this is another problem).

Which is then the correct way of running a spark-submit in client mode?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to include all jars using the --jars option, you will have to create a small script to enumerate them. This part is a bit sub-optimal.

Comment: Can you get him started with a small example?